# What does @ do in Postgres function calls?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out what a @ does in a Postgres function call. It is the worst term try to google or search for in the documentation.

I can do:

```
SELECT @extract(epoch FROM valid_to - valid_from) FROM...
```

and

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM valid_to - valid_from) FROM...
```

both seems to work. The version with @ I found in a example and I just don't find the purpose of it in any documentation or by googling.

Anyone that knows what this is or can point out where to read more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` symbol is an [operator for absolute value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html), it's the same as `abs(val)`. It does not do anything more written before a function call than getting the absolute value of the returned function result if that is valid (number type).